# Refresh an iframe from another iframe

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, api, controller

I have two inline VF pages added in the standard detail page layout. Both are inter-dependent and used for API callouts and has data from a custom object used for storing API reponse.

Is it possible to refresh the other page from the first one without causing an entire detail page refresh?